# how to use labels in subfloat

Tags: subfloats

```
\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat[Original]{{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{cata_orig.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Imposter]{{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{cata_impos.png} }}%
    \caption{Catalog Images}%
    \label{fig:cata}%
\end{figure}
```

In my latex file, when I do `Fig. \ref{fig:cata}` it compiles it to `Fig. 4`. But how do I refer `cata_orig.png` which is labeled `(a)` in compiling.

```
\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat[Original]{{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{cata_orig.png} \label{fig:hello}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Imposter]{{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{cata_impos.png} }}%
    \caption{Catalog Images}%
    \label{fig:cata}%
\end{figure}
```

I added a `\label{}` in the subfloat but when I try to refer it using `\protect\subref{fig:hello}`, it compiles to `(a)`. I want it to say `4 (a)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Update:* A modern version (replacing `subfig` by the more modern `subcaption`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{4cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cata_orig.png}
    \caption{Original}\label{fig:orig}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}{4cm}
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{cata_impos.png}
    \caption{Imposter}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Catalog Images}%
    \label{fig:cata}%
\end{figure}
\ref{fig:orig}
\end{document}
```

---

Here's one option (adding the reference to the caption):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat[Original\label{fig:orig}]{{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{cata_orig.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Imposter]{{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{cata_impos.png} }}%
    \caption{Catalog Images}%
    \label{fig:cata}%
\end{figure}
\ref{fig:orig}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `%` at the end of some of the lines?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq There is none (in this case). They have been copied from the question's code example.